# Bloom filter usage

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bloom-filter

I am struggling to understand the usefulness of the bloom filter.  I get its underlying logic, space compaction, fast lookups, false positives etc.  I just cannot put that concept into a real-life situation as being beneficial.  One frequent application is use of bloom filters in web caching.  We use bloom filter to determine whether a given URL is in the cache or not.  Why don't we simply access the cache to determine that?  If we get a yes, we still need to go to cache to retrieve the webpage (which might not be there), but in case of a no, we could have got the same answer using the cache (which is probably optimized for fast lookups anyway?).

Comment: Yes, the web cache is "optimized for fast lookups" by using a Bloom filter. What do you think "optimized for fast lookups" means for a web cache?

Comment: Well, how are the concrete webpage entries stored then? they have to be stored in some form of data structure (HashMap, DB etc.) for retrieval, as Bloom filter does not store any data, only answers the question of "membership/presence"

Comment: The point of a Bloom filter is to rule out false negatives. It's very fast and cheap to find out if something is definitely not in the cache. In that case, you go out and fetch it. Otherwise you look it up in the cache, which could imply a disk access. If you know that it's not in the cache because the Bloom filter told you, you save a disk access and fetch the page from the internet more quickly.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Bloom filters are designed for situations where a false negative is a Very Bad Thing and a false positive is acceptable.

For example, suppose that you are making a web browser and have a known blacklist of scam websites.  Your blacklist is massive - in the hundreds of gigabytes - so you can't ship it with the browser.  However, you can store it on your own servers.  In that case, you could ship the browser with a Bloom filter of an appropriate size that holds all the URLs.  Before visiting a site, you look it up in the filter.  Then, if you get a "no" answer, you're guaranteed that the URL is not blacklisted and can just visit the site.  If you get a "yes" answer, the site might be evil, so you can have the browser call up your main server to get the real answer.  The fact that you can save a huge number of calls to the server here without ever sacrificing accuracy is important.

The cache idea is similar to this setup.  You can query the filter to see if the page is in the cache.  If you get a "no" answer, you're guaranteed it's not cached and can do an expensive operation to pull the data from the main source.  Otherwise, you can then check the cache to see if it really is there.  In rare instances you might need to check the cache, see that it isn't there, then pull from the main source, but you will never accidentally miss something really in cache.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sending visited urls to a central server? Does not sound like a good idea

Comment: @BeniBela- IIRC, this was the approach Google Chrome used early on.  I agree that it's a privacy issue, though.

Comment: You could do it either way, but typically (IIRC) you'd just store URLs so you don't have to download the page to see whether it's legit.

Answer (score 5):

Bloom filters may be useful when *both* of the following conditions are met:

- A False Negative is unacceptable
- Cost of lookup is expensive relative to the cost of lookup in a Bloom Filter

The first point is pretty simple. The second point generally becomes significant when a Bloom Filter can be
stored in primary memory but the actual lookup may take database hits which can be very "costly" relative to
performing some number of hashes on the key followed by in-memory lookup (ie. a Bloom filter).

If only one of the above criteria are met, then Bloom Filters are not the best solution to the problem.

Savings come when one can eliminate a costly lookup because it is known there is no possibility of getting a match. This is the value of the first point - Bloom Filters do not generate false negatives so if a match is not found in the filter there is no point going to the next, more costly step, of retrieving the data associated with the key.

When the filter has a hit then a costly lookup is required to verify the hit (eliminate false positive) and retrieve related data. Here there is a possibilty of not finding anything due to a false positive and this is why the filter needs to be tuned to minimize this risk to an acceptable level. A functional Bloom filter must have a low false positive rate so the overall cost of lookup remains low.

Now if, as you say, your cache is already optomized for fast lookup then the utility of a Bloom filter may be questionalble.

Answer (score 3):

the problem is that your example isn't so great.

in a web cache, if the url is not present, you have to make an expensive call to the net anyway, so saving a disk access is not a big deal.  so you're right to question this (and Diego Basch's comment is not very well thought out, imho).

so i went looking for why you used that example.  and it turns out that the wikipedia article mentions that the squid web cache uses bloom filters.  but they're *not* used in the way you described.  instead they're used to decide which cache to select from amongst a set of distributed caches.  and they're used mainly to save space (because squid can cache a *lot* of objects, so these tables would otherwise be very large).

for more info on squid and bloom filters see http://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/CacheDigests

otherwise, the other answer here, from templatetypedef, is fine - checking for bad sites is a much better example.