# Best filter for MANET

Tags: filter, adhoc, bloom-filter, adhoc-queries, ad-hoc-network

I know about Bloom filter. 
 It is very useful where storage requirement is less and where we need to check only whether element is "**definitely not exist**" or "**may exist**" e.g. mobile devices, browser in-memory.

[As Best example given by Tarun](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4282375/what-is-the-advantage-to-using-bloom-filters#answer-30247022)

I need to know at least 2/3 better & faster filter than bloom filter where there is less storage required?

I need a filter or any better technique than bloom filter which can be useful in Mobile ad hoc network for storing device ip addresses and identifying address collisions.

Answer (score 2):

Not that much better than a Bloom Filter, but you can take a look into [Cuckoo Filters](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf). However, it will be harder for you to find an open source implementation; here is one in [Go](https://github.com/seiflotfy/cuckoofilter).

Citing from the original [Cuckoo Filter paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf):

> Cuckoo filters improve upon Bloom filters in three ways: (1) support
>   for deleting items dynamically; (2) better lookup performance; and (3)
>   better space efficiency for applications requiring low false positive
>   rates ( < 3%).

Comment: on github,why file extensions are given as .go ?

Comment: @pathe because that implementation is written in the [Go programming language](https://golang.org/).

Comment: @pathe You would have to try to understand it and port it to java.